# How to properly create variables from selector strings in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nav

So here's my issue, I'm doing mobile styling for hover effects for a website using jquery. Although I've been putting the elements I want affected by my mobile stylings into variables. Though my code doesn't work whenever I do this though. I'm not too sure what it is that I'm doing wrong but here's a snippet of my jquery script to get an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
$(function ($) {

     var slidebar = new $.slidebars({siteClose:true, scrollLock:true}), 
         ua = navigator.userAgent,
         navslide1 = $('nav.slide ul li:nth-child(1) a.mobile-nav-hover');
         // I'm trying to create a variable for nav.slide that works. --%>


      if (/iPod|iPad|iPhone|Android/.test(ua)) {

           $('nav.slide ul li a').removeClass('hover').addClass('mobile-nav-hover');

           // This is where I'm having problems. If I use the variable this code won't work. --!>
           navslide1.on('touchstart click', function(){

                 navslide1.css({

                       "background-color":"#ffffff",
                       "color":"#000000"

                 });

            }).on('touchend click', function(){

                   setTimeout(function(){
                       navslide1.css({

                              "background-color":"transparent",
                              "color":"#ffffff"

                       });
                  }, 120);

   }); 

      }

});
```

If anyone can help me out in figuring out what's wrong then that would be great!

**NOTE:**
When I run this code, no errors pop up in the console, but the code snippet won't work period if I use the navslide1 variable.

Comment: You should explain what exactly is going wrong. Are there errors in the console? Does *anything* happen? If so, what?

Comment: Added a note in my post answering that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is basically doomed to fail. This line:

```
     navslide1 = $('nav.slide ul li:nth-child(1) a.mobile-nav-hover');
```

creates a jQuery object that includes all the elements in the DOM that match the selector **at the point that the code is executed.**  If that's before you've added the class "mobile-nav-hover" to any element, then it'll be empty.

What you probably want to do is use delegated event handling. Make that variable just be the selector string:

```
navslide1 = 'nav.slide ul li:nth-child(1) a.mobile-nav-hover';
```

Then:

```
   $("body").on('touchstart click', navslide1, function() {
       $(navslide1).css({

           "background-color": "#ffffff",
           "color": "#000000"

       });

   }).on('touchend click', navslide1, function() {

       setTimeout(function() {
           $(navslide1).css({

               "background-color": "transparent",
               "color": "#ffffff"

           });
       }, 120);
   });
```

You can do that outside the useragent test, if you want to, and just have the test add the class.

The whole thing might get a lot simpler if you used Modernizr or something to detect the availability of touch events. (Note that your current check wouldn't account for the many Windows-based PCs and tablets with touch screens.)  If you do that, then you don't have to check anything, and you don't have to add any classes; you can just prefix any selector string with ".touch" to make sure they only take effect on touch-enabled clients, or ".no-touch" on non-touch-enabled clients.

Comment: `navslide1.css` --> `$(navslide1).css` ??

Comment: @MartinErnst oops yes sorry I just c/p'd the whole thing

Comment: @MartinErnst OK fixed, though I wonder whether it should be `$(this)` insteadl.

Comment: Yeah, `$(this)` would be faster and shorter.

Comment: I am indeed using modernizr actually.

Comment: Question though, if I were to use modernizr to handle touch detection, then how would I detect when a user switches back to using a mouse. Say if the user were using a microsoft surface?

Comment: @user3631048 you can't detect that unfortunately.